# Enable Direct I/O mode in GlusterFS

Tags: fuse, glusterfs

1. The GlusterFS server will ignore the O_DIRECT flag by default, how to make the server work in direct-io mode?
2. By `mount -t glusterfs XXX:/testvol -o direct-io-mode=enable mountpoint`, the GlusterFS client will work in direct-io mode, but the file will be cached in the hosted server.

How to solve this problem that both of the client and the server work in direct-io mode?

Answer (score 0):

1. `direct-io-mode=enable`
2. enable  `performance.strict-o-direct`
3. disable `network.remote-dio`

These should be sufficient if your application does page-aligned I/O which is mandatory for `O_DIRECT`.